# Handling delayed responses from server - Django Web App

Tags: django, server, response

I have a situation where a user is filling in a form on a django web app. Under normal circumstances the user will submit the form, the server will store the form in the db and display a success message. But, under the assumption that there are multiple users trying to submit the form at the same time and the server is timing out due to large amount of requests, I want to find and integrate a solution that acts as a queue and stores the data of the users when it is free instead of giving timeouts to the users. I want to do this since I do not want the users to fill in the form again from scratch.

So, what is the best solution to this problem apart from increasing the server timeout settings? What package or method do I need to use to avoid the user's request from timing out and to be able to successfully store the user's form regardless of the delays.

Note: I want to host my webapp on a single shared server, due to budget limitations I cannot afford a Load Balancer and multiple servers even though adding multiple servers will solve the problem.

So far, I have only looked into increasing the timeout from default in django to find a solution to this problem, but I dont want to depend too much on it since adding a fixed length of timeout won't solve the issue. I am looking for an alternate solution to this problem.

Comment: How many concurrent users are you having filling in your form? A Django app deployed on even a small server configured correctly should handle dozens of concurrent requests with a reasonable latency. Are you using the Django development server or a tool like `gunicorn` or `uwsgi`?